# Is there an ANSI version for Copy?

Tags: delphi, unicode

Under Delphi XE, is there an ANSI version for Copy? 
I am using Copy a lot to copy pieces of a ANSI strings.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Altar the [Copy](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Copy) function in Delphi is a intrinsic function this means which is handled by the compiler rather than the run-time library.  depending of the parameters passed this function call the  `LStrCopy` or a `UStrCopy` internal functions

check this sample :

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;
Var
   s : AnsiString;
   u : string;
begin
  try
   s:='this is a ansi string';
   s:= Copy(s,1,5);
   Writeln(s);
   u:='this is a unicode string';
   u:= Copy(u,1,5);
   Writeln(u);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

### Now check the assembly code

```
Project91.dpr.12: s:='this is a ansi string';
004111DC B8787E4100       mov eax,$00417e78
004111E1 BA04134100       mov edx,$00411304
004111E6 E8314FFFFF       call @LStrAsg
Project91.dpr.13: s:= Copy(s,1,5);
004111EB 68787E4100       push $00417e78
004111F0 B905000000       mov ecx,$00000005
004111F5 BA01000000       mov edx,$00000001
004111FA A1787E4100       mov eax,[$00417e78]
004111FF E8A050FFFF       call @LStrCopy //call the ansi version of copy
Project91.dpr.14: Writeln(s);
00411204 A1EC2C4100       mov eax,[$00412cec]
00411209 8B15787E4100     mov edx,[$00417e78]
0041120F E84033FFFF       call @Write0LString
00411214 E8DF33FFFF       call @WriteLn
00411219 E8D22AFFFF       call @_IOTest
Project91.dpr.15: u:='this is a unicode string';
0041121E B87C7E4100       mov eax,$00417e7c
00411223 BA28134100       mov edx,$00411328
00411228 E8534EFFFF       call @UStrAsg
Project91.dpr.16: u:= Copy(u,1,5);
0041122D 687C7E4100       push $00417e7c
00411232 B905000000       mov ecx,$00000005
00411237 BA01000000       mov edx,$00000001
0041123C A17C7E4100       mov eax,[$00417e7c]
00411241 E8C654FFFF       call @UStrCopy //call the unicode version of copy
Project91.dpr.17: Writeln(u);
00411246 A1EC2C4100       mov eax,[$00412cec]
```

Comment: I use mixed types so this is why the compiler complains. How should I proceed? Typecast all my strings ANSI inside the Copy (the parameters) or I just put an $Warnings off around Copy?

Comment: Mixing your strings is a performance nightmare. Why don't you just convert where possible, all one way (Explicit AnsiString) or all the other (Explicitly go to String aka UnicodeString).

Comment: +1 for Warren: And in order to mix string and maintain performance, please ensure that when you call some high-level functions (like IntToStr or such), you're calling the Ansi or Unicode version... Not so easy... I had to create [my own set of dedicated functions to handle UTF-8 strings](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCommons.pas) with best performance available under Unicode version of Delphi. Function overloading may be difficult to track.

Answer (score 6):

Copy is a "compiler magic" routine, it is handled intrinsically by the compiler depending on what parameters you pass it (ANSI string, string, or dynamic array). You can just use Copy; it will work correctly with ANSI strings.

Comment: I hope there is a ANSI version that does not complain when I pass a ANSI string to it. So I don't have to typecast UNICODE to ANSI all over my code.

Comment: As I said, Copy already is ANSI. You don't have to typecast, and the compiler doesn't complain. Think of it as an overloaded procedure where one of the overloaded versions accepts ANSI string parameters.

Comment: Altar if you not mix unicode strings and ansi strings in the same call to `Copy` you will not receive any complains of the compiler.

Comment: Well, then this is why the compiler complains. I use mixed types.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, see this code:

```
const
     TheStart=13;
     TheEnd=69;
type
    TMyFileField: Array[TheStart..TheEnd] of Char; // This is a simplification of a field type on a file
procedure WriteWideStringToArrayOfChars(TheLiteral:WideString);
var
   MyFileField:TMyFileField; // This is a simplification, it is really a Field inside a File
   MyIndex:Integer;
begin
     for MyIndex:=1 to Max(Length(TheLiteral),1+TheEnd-TheStart)
     do begin // Will copy as many charactes as possible from TheLiteral to MyFileField
             MyFileField[MyIndex]:=Copy(TheLiteral,MyIndex,1)[1]; // This gives Copile Error: Incompatible types 'Char' and 'WideChar'
        end;
end;
```

The problem is that the WideString must be saved onto am Array of Char inside a file. So mix types must be done... and so, some loose of Unicode chars will occur, no way to avoid it.

The wanted: The compiler can compile it.

Solution1: Convert WideString to String prior to call Copy, or inside Copy.
Solution2: Convert WideChar to Char prior to assing.

Here are both solutions (remember some unicode chars could get lost)...

Solution1:

`MyFileField[MyIndex]:=Copy(UTF8Encode(TheLiteral),MyIndex,1)[1]; // Note: Unicode chars will not get lost, but converted, so beware of accent vocals, etc...`

or

`MyFileField[MyIndex]:=Copy(String(TheLiteral),MyIndex,1)[1]; // Note: Unicode chars will get lost, they will be converted to '?'`

Solution2:

`MyFileField[MyIndex]:=Char(Copy(TheLiteral,MyIndex,1)[1]); // Note: Unicode chars will get lost, they will be converted to '?'`

If anyone knows anthing better i would be glad to know.

I personally use `Copy(String(Literal),Start,NumberOfChars)` since normal accent letters are conserved and more important, length...

Example: Length(String('BlaBlaBlá')) -> 9
Example: Length(UTF8Encode('BlaBlaBlá')) -> More than 9 since the last 'á' is converted to multiple chars, etc...

Hope this can help someone!

Answer (score 0):

I did my own function. It could be useful and get right results instead of Copy(string(ansistr), i, l) on the Linux platform:

```
function AnsiCopy(const s: ansistring; StartIndex, Lenght: integer): ansistring;
begin
 SetLength(Result, Lenght);
 Move(s[StartIndex], Result[1], Lenght);
end;
```